# Complex aggregation with new data

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I'm having some troubles with data that are updated daily. I have a table that contains these fields :

```
CREATE TABLE t_analytics 
(
    t_date DATE,
    t_community INTEGER,
    t_user INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE t_user  
(
   t_id INTEGER,
   t_dep_id INTEGER,
   t_location_id INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO t_user 
VALUES (1, 10, 101), (2, 10, 102), (3, 10, 101);

INSERT INTO t_analytics 
VALUES ('2016-12-18', 1, 1), ('2016-12-18', 2, 1), ('2016-12-19', 1, 3);
```

And a fact table that contains these fields :

```
CREATE TABLE fact_test 
(
   t_date DATE,
   t_community INTEGER,
   t_location INTEGER,
   t_department INTEGER,
   t_register INTEGER
);
```

A register represents all users that did an action at some date or before,  on a community. To simplify, I didn't represent the actions in t_analytics, so let's say that it's when a user is present in this table.
So I can fill this table with the following query :

```
WITH date_range AS 
(
    SELECT  MIN(t_date) as start_date,
            MAX(t_date) as end_date
    FROM    t_analytics
)
INSERT INTO fact_test
    SELECT
        f.date,
        f.community_id, f.location_id, f.department_id,
        f.register
    FROM    
        generate_series((SELECT start_date FROM date_range), 
                        (SELECT end_date FROM date_range), '1 day') d
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT     
             A.t_date as date, A.t_community as community_id,
             U.t_dep_id as department_id, U.t_location_id as location_id,
             (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A2.t_user)
              FROM t_analytics A2
              INNER JOIN t_user U2 ON U2.t_id = A2.t_user
              WHERE A.t_date >= A2.t_date
                AND A.t_community = A2.t_community
                AND U.t_location_id = U2.t_location_id
                AND U.t_dep_id = U2.t_dep_id) as register
         FROM
             t_analytics A
         INNER JOIN 
             t_user U ON U.t_id = A.t_user
         WHERE  
             A.t_date >= (SELECT start_date FROM date_range)
             AND A.t_date <= (SELECT end_date FROM date_range)
         GROUP BY   
             A.t_date, A.t_community, U.t_dep_id, U.t_location_id) f ON f.date = d.date
WHERE 
    f.date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    f.date, f.register, f.community_id, f.department_id, f.location_id
ORDER BY 
    f.date;
```

So, for the tuple (location/department/community/date) the number of registers will increase only if a new one is present in t_analytics.

However, every day, my t_analytics table contains new values, and I'd like to recalculate the number of registers.
At the moment, I truncate the table and add all the new data, it takes like 15minutes and I guess it'll take hours in the next

**Example**

```
  CREATE TABLE new_data (
    t_date DATE,
    t_community INTEGER,
    t_user INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO new_data VALUES ('2016-12-20', 2, 1),('2016-12-20',2,3),('2016-12-20',1,2);

-- OR
-- tuple : date,community,user
INSERT INTO t_analytics VALUES ('2016-12-20', 2, 1),('2016-12-20',2,3),('2016-12-20',1,2);
```

It this case, the number of registers should be 2 for 
Date : 20.12.2016 
Community : 2
Location : 101
Department : 10 
Registers : 2

Is it possible to do that without any truncate ?

http://rextester.com/KNME8643

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does `t_analytics` contain only new values, or is it the full history of records and you're truncating your `fact_test` table every run?

Comment: A simple way to manage incremental loads is to utilize a timestamp or `IDENTITY` field on the source table to filter out records you have already processed. Then you need `MERGE` or `UPSERT` functionality, which is available starting with postgres 9.5 via `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE` so that if a tuple already exists you can just add to the number of registers, otherwise insert a new tuple.

Comment: I tested the merges, seems OK : http://rextester.com/NPMKZ1940